# Function with String Message, echos to screen, change the color of message

Tags: function, powershell, parameters, colors, write-host

Good Morning all,
***SOLVED***
Both responses worked hand in hand. Big Thanks to Scepticalist and Wasif Hasan for the examples!!

I have a logging function that has a message parameter. Through the function it writes the message with a text color of green. Is there a way to change that color for certain messages for the log? Below is the function.

```
Function Get-Logger { 
    param(
       [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
       [String]$message
    )

    $TimeStamp = Get-Date -Format "MM-dd-yyy hh:mm:ss"

    Write-Host $TimeStamp -NoNewline
    Write-Host `t $message -ForegroundColor Green
    $logMessage = "[$TimeStamp]  $message"
    $logMessage | Out-File -Append -LiteralPath $VerboseLogFile
}
```

For example as the log function is called it echo's back the message as green text, which is fine. But if I wanted to use the logging function to change the text of section headers to yellow is there a way to do that? Below is what I'm kind of talking about

```
Get-Logger "Hello Word Starting" -Foregroundcolor yellow -nonewline
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
Function Get-Logger { 
    param(
       [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)][String]$message,
       [validatescript({[enum]::getvalues([system.consolecolor]) -contains $_})][string]$messagecolor,
       [switch]$nonewline
    )

    $TimeStamp = Get-Date -Format "MM-dd-yyy hh:mm:ss"
    If ($nonewline){
        Write-Host `t $message -ForegroundColor $($messagecolor) -nonewline
    }
    Else {
        Write-Host `t $message -ForegroundColor $($messagecolor)
    }
    $logMessage = "[$TimeStamp]  $message"
    $logMessage | Out-File -Append -LiteralPath $VerboseLogFile
}
```

Then:

```
Get-Logger "Hello Word Starting" -messagecolour yellow -nonewline
```

Comment: That does work, I'm trying to get some more flexibility out of it so I don't have to identify the whole acceptable color range in the function.

Also the `-nonewline` section still pulls up as an error

Comment: You can pull the default colours from PS with code and then use them as a validate set - I think I have an example somewhere, but it's relatively complex for such a small function.
If you want -nonewline optional then you'll have to add it as a parameter for the function and code for it.  
Edit: As Wasan shows below :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to add another switch "NoNewLine". So add this in param block:

```
[switch]$nonewline
```

And in the function body, do:

```
If ($nonewline){
  Write-Host `t $message -ForegroundColor $($messagecolour) -nonewline
}
Else {
  Write-Host `t $message -ForegroundColor $($messagecolour)
}
```

You can now add a validatescript on param block to validate color:

```
[validatescript({[enum]::getvalues([system.consolecolor]) -contains $_})][string]$messagecolor
```

Thanks to @Scepticalist

Comment: Here you go - this will retrieve the colours: [enum]::GetValues([System.ConsoleColor])

Comment: @Scepticalst thanks for the help! Edited the answer and added ValidateScript.